# Confusion on Polchinski P.67

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, path-integral

I am reading Polchinski's String Theory Volume I. While I am learning the basics of string scatterings in Ch.3, I went back to chapter 2 and review the part of vertex operators. However, I found that I didn't really understand eq. 2.8.18 and the paragraph below when I tried to derive what he said.

In the book,

> The state–operator isomorphism is an important but unfamiliar idea and
>   so it is useful to give also a more explicit path integral derivation. Consider
>   a unit disk in the $z$-plane, with local operator $A$ at the origin and with
>   the path integral fields $φ$ fixed to some specific boundary values $φ_b$ on
>   the unit circle. The path integral over the fields $φ_i$ on the interior of the
>   disk with $φ_b$ held fixed produces some functional $Ψ_A[φ_b]$,
>   $$Ψ_A[φ_b] = \int 
> [dφ_i]_{φ_b} \exp(−S[φ_i])A(0) . $$
>   A functional of the fields is the Schrodinger representation of a state, so
>   this is a mapping from operators to states. The Schrodinger representation, which assigns a complex amplitude to each field configuration, has
>   many uses. It is often omitted from field theory texts, the Fock space
>   representation being emphasized.
>
> To go the other way, start with some state $Ψ[φ_b]$. Consider a path
>   integral over the annular region $1 \geq |z| \geq r$, with the fields $φ_b$ on the
>   outer circle fixed and the fields $φ_b$ integrated over the inner circle as
>   follows:
>
> $$\int[dφ'_b][dφi]_{φ_b,φ'_b} \exp(−S[φ_i])r^{−L_0−\tilde{L}_0}Ψ[φ'_b].  \quad(2.8.18)$$
>   That is, the integral is weighted by the state (functional) $r^{−L_0−\tilde{L}_0}Ψ[φ_b]$. Now, the path integral over the annulus just corresponds to propagating
>   from $|z| = r$ to $|z| = 1$, which is equivalent to acting with the operator
>   $r^{L_0+\tilde{L}_0}$. This undoes the operator acting on $Ψ$, so the path integral (2.8.18)
>   is again $Ψ[φ_b]$. Now take the limit as $r → 0$. The annulus becomes a disk,
>   and the limit of the path integral over the inner circle can be thought of
>   as defining some local operator at the origin. By construction the path
>   integral on the disk with this operator reproduces $Ψ[φ_b]$ on the boundary.

$$ \Psi[\phi_b] = \int d[\phi'_b]d[\phi_i]_{\phi_b,\phi'_b}\exp(-S[\phi_i])r^{-L_0-\tilde{L}_0}\Psi[\phi'_b] $$

1. If I follow (A.1.15), I could not see how the factor $r^{-L_0-\tilde{L}_0}$ arises.
2. As he mentioned, the integral means propagation from $|z|=r$ to $|z|=1$. My previous understanding is the propagation in $r$-direction is the time evolution so we act $\exp(-iHt)$ on it. The time direction is $\mbox{Im}(w)$ in the cylinder coordinate $(z=\exp(-iw))$, so we have $\exp(-iH \mbox{Im}(w)) = r^{-i(L_0+\tilde{L}_0)}$ ?

My sincere thank for your time and effort on explaining it. :)

Thank @Prahar for the comment. I guessed his is referring to euclidean world-sheet, thanks for confirming this.

Comment: Please include all relevant information into the post, in particular equations you are talking about - if I am a bit familiar with the field, I should not have to open a *specific book* to understand your question.

Comment: We are working in Euclidean time. So the time evolution operator is $e^{-H \tau} = e^{- H \text{Im} w }$. Then, $r = |z| = e^{  \text{Im} w }$. Thus, $e^{- H \tau } = r^{-H} = r^{-L_0 - {\tilde L}_0}$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What do you think about my first question?

Answer (score 1):

I guess Joe is taking Euclidian time evolution as $\ e^{H\tau}=r^H\ (w=\sigma+i\tau)\ $ which can be seen from the paragraph below (2.8.18). Hence we have (omitting “b”)

$$
\Psi[\phi]=\langle\phi|\Psi\rangle
=\langle\phi|r^Hr^{-H}|\Psi\rangle
=\int[d\phi’] \langle\phi|r^H|\phi’\rangle
\langle\phi’|r^{-H}|\Psi\rangle\\
=\int [d\phi’][d\psi]_{\phi,\phi’}\exp(-S[\psi])\ r^{-H}\Psi[\phi’].
$$

This is the meaning of (2.8.18), see (2.6.10) $H=L_0+\tilde L_0-\dfrac{c+\tilde c}{24}$.

Joe is omitting “$c$” here ?