# Conformal invariance of the massless scalar field action

Tags: symmetry, conformal-field-theory, classical-field-theory

The massless scalar field action on Minkowski background is given by
\begin{equation}
S[\phi]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^D}d^Dx~\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi.
\end{equation}
This action is often referred as one of the easiest CFT one can have so I would like to show that is it conformally invariant. If we only consider dilatations $x'^\mu\mapsto x^\mu+\epsilon x^\mu$ for example, the scalar field transforms as
\begin{equation}
\delta\phi(x)=\epsilon x^\mu\partial_\mu\phi(x).
\end{equation}
I can't manage to show that the action only changes up to a boundary term. How would one show that ?

[EDIT]

I already saw a lot of proofs of this (e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/647457/proof-that-free-scalar-field-is-conformally-invariant)) but they always transform the metric or the partial derivatives. This is equivalent of considering the trivial action of a diffeomoprhism that acts on each object in the integral and therefore trivially leaves it invariant. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I suggest that you use the relation $\eta_{\hat{\mu}\hat{\nu}} = \Omega^2\eta_{\mu\nu}$ where $\Omega^2$ is a function of the space-time co-ordinates and also use the transformation $\partial_{\hat{\mu}} = \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\hat {\mu}}}\frac{\partial\,}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\,.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that free scalar field is conformally invariant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/647457/proof-that-free-scalar-field-is-conformally-invariant)

Comment: I don't want to transform the metric or the partial derivatives because this would result in a trivial coordinate transformation, under which any integral is invariant. Am I wrong ?

Comment: That is not how the scalar field transforms under dilations. Rather, the transformation has the form $\delta \phi(x) = \epsilon ( x^\mu \partial_\mu + \Delta ) \phi(x)$ for a particular choice of $\Delta$. You can work out what this choice is.

Comment: Why is that ? Conformal transformations are just a generalization of Poincaré transformations no ? And also performing the expansion of $\phi(x+\epsilon x)$, we find that $\delta\phi=\epsilon x^\mu\partial_\mu\phi$.

Comment: @xpsf - conformal transformations are NOT a generalization of Poincar\'e transformation. They involve a Weyl transformation in ADDITION to the conformal diffeomorphism you are referring to. There is a reason you've seen a lot of proofs involving metric transformations. It's because that's what a conformal transformation IS!

Comment: Ok, I think that the terminology was not clear to me indeed. Thank you for this clarification, I now understand.